# How do I get an Canon Pixma MP150 to print?

Tags: printing, canon

I succesfully installed my Canon Pixma MP150 printer (and scanner) in Ubuntu 12.04, made it the default printer, but i cannot print anything. Watching the printing queue, i see that the printer receives my documents but just for a few seconds after which the queue gets empty without anything getting actually printed.

I tried to print from large pdf's to quite tiny txt files. I reinstalled the printer from cups web-based interface (127.0.0.1:631) but again, no luck.

Any ideea on the matter?

Comment: Look at the CUPS tab labeled Administration. On the right side of the screen, under the heading Server, there should be a button to View Error Log. Click that and see if there are messages to help determine exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Install the printer in cups-browserinterface as mp140 with the **mp150 driver**.
That used to be the driver in all the previous ubuntu´s.

This has solved my problems wich sounds exactly like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I simply re-installed the driver like this:

- In the **Printer Configuration** window, right-click on your Printer and select **Properties**
- Then in the **Settings** Tab, modify the driver by selecting the right device, and erase the old driver with the new.

Don't need to restart, it works!